# UILabel textcolor is not applying when I scroll UITableView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am a very beginner in iOS and in my project. I have created one sample "`Expandable-Listview`" and  I have added here one `UILabel` on my `HeaderView` and  it's working fine

my main requirement is here when I expand the cell I want to change `UILabel` "`textcolor`" as "`RED`" and when i collapsed the cell then `UILabel` "`textcolor`" color must be "`ORANGE`"

for this, I have written code but when I scroll the `TableList` `UILabel` "`textcolor`" color is changing yo "`ORANGE`" color even when the cell was not in the collapsed state.

Please help me some one what did I do here wrong?

### my code:-

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UILabel *viewLabel;
    BOOL collapsed;
    NSInteger collapsedSection;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initialization];
}

#pragma  mark - Initialization

-(void)initialization
{
    arrayForBool=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    sectionTitleArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                       @"Apple",
                       @"Strawberry",
                       @"Grapes",
                       @"Orange",
                       @"Banana",
                       @"Papaya",
                       @"Guava",
                       @"pineapple",
                       nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[sectionTitleArray count]; i++) {
        [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView DataSource and Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return section+2;
    }
    else
    return 0;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *cellid=@"hello";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
    }
        BOOL manyCells  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

             /********** If the section supposed to be closed *******************/
        if(!manyCells)
        {
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

            cell.textLabel.text=@"";
        }
             /********** If the section supposed to be Opened *******************/
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section],indexPath.row+1];
            cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"];
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ;
        }
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

                  /********** Add a custom Separator with cell *******************/
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 40, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-15, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [sectionTitleArray count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    /*************** Close the section, once the data is selected ***********************************/
    [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

     [_expandableTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue]) {
        return 40;
    }
    return 0;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}

#pragma mark - Creating View for TableView Section

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280,40)];
    sectionView.tag=section;

    for (id subview in sectionView.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        } else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-10, 40)];
    viewLabel.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    viewLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    viewLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"List of %@",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]];
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];

    if (collapsedSection ==  section) {
        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }else{
        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    /********** Add a custom Separator with Section view *******************/

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 40, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-15, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [sectionView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    /********** Add UITapGestureRecognizer to SectionView   **************/

    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [sectionView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return  sectionView;
}
#pragma mark - Table header gesture tapped

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

   // collapsedSection =

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

    collapsedSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

       collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

        for (int i=0; i<[sectionTitleArray count]; i++) {

            if (indexPath.section==i) {

                [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
            }
        }

        [_expandableTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your  `viewForHeaderInSection` you have set the `textcolor` to `orange` so when you reload/scroll the `tableView` , `viewForHeaderInSection` is called and change the color. Put your expand/collapse condition in this method and set your color accordingly

Comment: You have already put the condition in  viewForHeaderInSection  like following. Isn't it working? if not then there must be something wrong with  the collapseSection value.        if (collapsedSection ==  section) {
        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }else{
        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }

Comment: i mean when i expand one cell that cell UILabel textcolor only must be "RED" and when i collapsed that cell then UILabel textcolor must be "ORANGE" based on my code when i collapse cell UILabel textcolor not changing as "ORANGE"

Comment: That means your (collapsedSection == section) is always true. Log your  collapsedSection value where you are setting this.

Comment: you mean    collapsedSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag; right? and i have tried this way also but when i collapse cell UILabel Color is not changing

Comment: If you are assigning collapsedSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag then set  headerTapped.view.tag = section in your viewforHeader. Also log the gestureRecognizer.view.tag value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97825/discussion-between-abhiram-and-muneeba).

Answer (score 0):

In your gesture Recognizer, you reload a tableview section:

```
        [_expandableTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

This will implicitly call your viewForHeaderInSection function.
So you have to set your Label text color in viewForHeaderInSection:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280,40)];
    sectionView.tag=section;

    viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-10, 40)];
    viewLabel.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    viewLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    viewLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"List of %@",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]];

    /*** CHANGE COLOR HERE ***/
    if (collapsedSection == section) {
        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }else{
        viewLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];

    /********** Add a custom Separator with Section view *******************/

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 40, _expandableTableView.frame.size.width-15, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [sectionView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    /********** Add UITapGestureRecognizer to SectionView   **************/

    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [sectionView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return  sectionView;
}

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{ 
    /*** SAVE COLLPASED SECTION HERE ***/
    collapsedSection = gestureRecognizer.view.tag;
}
```

Comment: hi what is that "collapsedSection" and "indexPath"  inside the sectionHeaderTapped method it's showing exceptions like unresolved identifiers, please explain clearly because i am very new for ios

Comment: indexPath.section would be your gestureRecognizer.view.tag, collapsedSection is a "@property NSInteger collapsedSection;"

Comment: i am asking when i expand the cell then only i want to change textcolor as "RED" and when i collpse cells i want to change  textcolor as "ORANGE" using your code it's not working fine

Comment: see i have updated my code with your suggestions but that's not working fine

Comment: i mean when i expand one cell then UILabel "textcolor" color must be "RED" and when i collapse cell then UILabel "textcolor" color must be "ORANGE"